# Jsoup Help for Android - How do i get the text in an element from a table?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

http://msu.esuds.net/RoomStatus/showRoomStatus.i?locationId=1016364

When I inspect element the table in the link provided the table's name is `table.room_status`.

But when I try to tell if the washers/dryers are available with:

```
private void getWebsite(){
    Log.d("getWebsite","runs");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("run","runs");
            final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.parseTest);
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://msu.esuds.net/RoomStatus/showRoomStatus.i?locationId=1028671").get();
                for (Element table : doc.select("table.room_status")) {
                    Log.d("table","runs");
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                        Log.d("row","runs");
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");
                        if (tds.size() == 6) {
                            Elements font = tds.get(4).getElementsByTag("font");
                            builder.append(font.first().text());
                            Log.d("font","runs");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                builder.append("Error: ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}
```

The only logcats I see are `Log.d("getWebsite", "runs)` and `Log.d("run", "runs")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your browser's developer tools and you'll see that when loading the site, after the `GET` request you have a `POST` request that fetches the table. Change your request to get that page. It is also useful to add the user-agent string to the request:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://msu.esuds.net/RoomStatus/machineStatus.i?bottomLocationId=1016486")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0")
            .post();
```